# No space for [blank-space]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

This tag, [blank-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blank-space), doesn't actually describe anything and is used for questions that are not related to each other. Is there a way to remove/lock it?

Comment: *There should be no [blank-space]s*

Comment: *Some [blank-space] is in need of trimming*

Comment: Let's trim the [blank-space].  But that's enough puns for one day. ;)

Comment: Not surprisingly, the tag wiki is a blank space too.

Comment: @TinyGiant suggested an edit for that.

Comment: I suggested a tag wiki for [tag:blank-space], and it was approved

Comment: @penne12: You should save a copy of that wiki in your answer, against the day it's autodeleted (by disappearance of the tag), and then the tag reappears.... :(

Comment: @BenVoigt Done. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Looks like it's gone now.  We'll have to wait a full day to see it take effect, but for now...it's burninated.

Comment: Thanks for the hard work @Makoto.

Comment: You're welcome.  I suppose the "thanks" in this scenario would suffice enough. ;)

Comment: since it's a new day, is that pun ok?

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Well that makes the title look like nonsense so I say no.

Comment: I obviously am partial in this but I do think it's still readable... I'll let you rollback if you think it should @DavidG :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier I'm all for the puns (within reason) but I saw this title in the list of questions and had no clue what it was about. I'll edit it.

Comment: And now, when you go to the [page for blank-space posts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blank-space), you see a big blank space.  Don't write anything in.

Comment: ♫ 'Cause I've got a [blank-space] baby, and I'll write your name. ♫

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's around 100 questions there that could use some attention.  Those of us with 2K+ reputation should go through it and start dealing with the questions there.

It *looks* like most of the questions concern strings and string formatting, so [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string) is fine to tag those with.  Others ask about blank spaces or data, so we'll have to evaluate those cases individually.

As with all burnination requests, **please don't just remove the tag!** If there's more to clean up, please do so.  We probably won't see that question for a very long time, so any work done to clean it up would make it better when it resurfaces.

Comment: I went over the questions that I didn't have in my ignore tags and edited/cv-ed/flagged and removed tags on the way. I didn't touch questions without answers and questions that were closed. There are now 51 left.

Comment: Honestly, is `string` any better, though?

Comment: @Rob:  I'm taking it case by case.  A blank space *is* a string, so in the questions where it makes sense to simply say "string", I'm allowing the question to do so.  There are some that don't pertain to strings, so those get different treatment.

Answer (score 4):

I suggested a tag wiki for the [blank-space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blank-space). If it does ever come back again, I copied and pasted it into this answer, for future purposes. Suggested by Ben Voigt (thanks!)

## Usage Guidance

DO NOT USE: This tag doesn't help categorize your question.

A blank space is an empty space. It could refer to a whitespace character, CSS padding, a null/nil value, a `<br>` tag in HTML, a song by [Taylor Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_Swift), or really anything else.

## Tag Wiki

### Do not use this tag

It doesn't help anyone answer your question faster, it isn't descriptive of what you are trying to do, and does it help does not help in any other way.

Meta Topic: [No space for [blank-space]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311811/should-the-blank-space-tag-be-removed)

### Definition

Blank space is an empty space. It could refer to a [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) character: ( ), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) padding (`padding-top: 100px`), a null/nil value, a `<br>` tag in [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), [a song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-ORhEE9VVg) by Taylor Swift, or really anything else.

### Example:

### Alternatives:

If you can't thing of what your topic actually refers to, here's some suggestions:

- Your language - [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python), [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript), [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php), or even [lolcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lolcode).
- [string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/string), if your question is super-related to strings (formatting, etc.)
- [null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/null) (or [nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nil) in [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby), [none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/none) in Python), or your question is related to the absence of a value.
- [whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/whitespace) if your question is related to whitespace ( ,     , `\s`...)
- [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) if you are trying to detect blank characters (`\s`)

```
#Do not use this tag

It doesn't help anyone answer your question faster, it isn't descriptive of what you are trying to do, and does it help does not help in any other way.

Meta Topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311811/should-the-blank-space-tag-be-removed

#Definition

Blank space is a empty space. It could refer to a whitespace character: (` `), css padding (`padding-top: 100px`), a null/nil value, a `
` tag in html, [a song][0] by Taylor Swift, or really anything else.

#Example:











#Alternatives:

If you can't thing of what your topic actually refers to, here are some suggestions:

- Your language - python, javascript, ruby, php, or even lolcode.

- string, if your question is super-related to strings (formatting, etc.)

- null (or nil in ruby, none in Python), or your question is related to the absence of a value.

- whitespace if your question is related to whitespace (` `, `    `, `\s`...)

- regex if you are trying to detect blank characters (`\s`)
```

Comment: "Black space"...?

Comment: Honestly, "Do not use" is *less* useful than no tag wiki...like I said earlier, there's only a handful of these questions, so it's not terribly difficult to go through them and fix 'em up.